# Choosing a platform and library for 3D plot of math expression with matrix transformation

Tags: math, cross-platform, plot, java-3d

I am trying to write a program that can 
- do 3d plot with mouse rotation and scaling
- allows users to input a transformation matrix and transform the plot

I would like this program to be cross-platform and so thinking of writing as a Java Applet so that it can be embedded in the webpage. But I don't know which Math 3D Graphic Library to use. Also, I also want to run it on tablets (maybe in both iOS and Android) and gives the touch interface. Then, I figure that Java Applet would not be the best.

Any suggestion on platform and library and any other choice of tools that will do the above things with really good performance?

Comment: I find most good plotting libraries tend to cost money. Useful information to add might therefor be if you're willing to pay for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [jzy3d](http://www.jzy3d.org) you can easily draw 3d surfaces, scatters, barcharts, and other common mathematical charts. It has full mouse/keyboard support. It does not hide access to raw opengl so that you remain free to customize whatever you want.

Version 0.9 relies on jogl2 (opengl bindings for java), which let you run the API easily on win, mac & unix. Although not provided by Jzy3d, you may easily use the JOGL applet launcher to run 3d over the web. JOGL2 is also able to run on Android so jzy3d should also be able to run Android.

Concerning iOS, are you sure it supports applets? Anyway, I fear JOGL2 won't support iOS. You might discuss that point on [jogamp](http://www.jogamp.org) which as a very reactive forum.

Jzy3d API is BSD licensed, so you can use it in any commercial project.

Hope that helps!

Martin

(disclaimer: I'm the author)

Comment: what do you think about JavaScript using webGL or similar tools instead of Java Applet? will it be better?

Comment: Sure it will be better, furthermore there might be some libs to deal with touch interface... but you have to do all the work from scratch (unless there is a javascript equivalent to jzy3d but I haven't seen one up to now).

Comment: @Martin I am also searching for a lib that I can use in android to plot surface charts and Jzy3d really looks awesome just what I need, so what you are saying is I could import  Jzy3d in my android project and just use it? Most of the forums said you should first modify code to take out AWT dependencies, is this correct or did it change? I am finding it dificult to find an example of an ported version. Could you help me in pointing me in the correct way?

Comment: Right you have to exclude AWT sources while building jzy3d, but I prepared the work for this by isolating awt-related sources in a dedicated source folder (https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/tree/master/jzy3d-api/src/awt/). Let me know when you achieve a build on android. Join us on forum or github issue panel if you have problems.